# Can Cross join and in can be same query?

Tags: sql, join

I am trying to club two tables using cross join as below

```
select * from nasda_objects  
cross join (select * from nasda_objects);
```

And the same is working

But when I try to use in in the left table of cross join its not working

```
select * from nasda_objects where co_gid in (450,550,650)  
cross join (select * from nasda_objects);
```

So in and cross join in same query are not supported ?

Comment: You refer to two tables in the text of your question but you've only referred to one table in the query.

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
select * from nasda_objects cross join (select * from nasda_objects)
where co_gid in (450,550,650);
```

ie, you need to add the `where` condition at the last when you have joined the tables.

Comment: Maybe add some explanation to make it more instructive?

Comment: @GertArnold:- Tried to add that but I am not sure what OP is looking for so waiting for him to respond.

Answer (score 0):

The properly structured query:

```
select *
from nasda_objects cross join (select * from nasda_objects);
where co_gid in (450, 550, 650)
```

will not work because `co_gid` is not defined.  So you know, `CROSS JOIN` is an operator in SQL that works *only* in the `FROM` clause.  The `WHERE` clause goes after the `FROM` clause.

To prevent a syntax error, you need table aliases.  I presume that this is what you want:

```
select *
from nasda_objects o1 cross join nasda_objects o2
where o1.co_gid in (450, 550, 650) ;
```

Note that the subquery is also not needed.

I'm not sure why you would want to do this.  Usually a `cross join` to the same table is not needed.